# Keep only highest frequency term per unique label in DFM

Tags: r, quanteda

My problem involves trimming/selecting terms in a quanteda dfm based on prior knowledge that generally only 1 term in each document is significant in determining the correct label. There are multiple tools for trimming or selecting but none seem to do what I need as they do not seem to take the resulting labels into account. If I am trying to reinvent the wheel, please direct me to the correct approach, but otherwise here is a small data set with an explanation of the mechanics I would like to employ in order to get my list of terms (which I can then apply to the starting dfm with dfm_select)

Starting dfm looks like this (data.frame for simplicity). t1...t6 are the names of the occurring terms, and each frequency is either 1 or 0

```
my_dfm <- data.frame(t1=c(0,0,0,1,0,0), t2=c(0,1,1,0,0,0), t3=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), t4=c(0,0,1,1,1,0),t5=c(1,0,0,0,1,1))
my_dfm

#    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
#  1  0  0  1  0  1
#  2  0  1  1  0  0
#  3  0  1  1  1  0
#  4  1  0  0  1  0
#  5  0  0  0  1  1
#  6  0  0  0  0  1
```

The labels will be not be grouped, but for clarity in this example are grouped together

```
my_labels <- data.frame(my_labels=c('a','a','a','b','b','b'))
my_labels
#   my_labels
# 1         a
# 2         a
# 3         a
# 4         b
# 5         b
# 6         b
```

The rule I want to apply for trimming my dfm is that for each unique label {a, b}, only choose enough unique terms to ensure that each document {1..6} has at least 1 matching term, prioritizing those terms which occur the most across each group of documents. So in this  example, for label **a** and **b**, the totals look like this

```
# a freq totals
c(0,2,3,1,1)
# 0 2 3 1 1
#
# b freq totals
c(1,0,0,2,2)
# 1 0 0 2 2
```

At this point I need to determine which of the terms satisfy the rule. For label a, t3 satisfies all three documents, and for label b, t4 and t5 combined satisfy those corresponding 3 documents

```
# a_keep
c(0,0,1,0,0)
# 0 0 1 0 0
#
# b_keep
c(0,0,0,1,1)
# 0 0 0 1 1
```

The overlapping "keep" vector looks like this:

```
# keep
c(0,0,1,1,1)
# 0 0 1 1 1
```

So I can now apply this to my dfm and only keep t3, t4, t5

I can see a way of doing this through several loops but not attempted *yet*. Logic: for each label count the term freqs. Then starting with highest total term check if each document is accounted for, if not, add next highest freq term and so on until all docs accounted for. Then keep the combined set of terms). What I would like though, is to find there is actually a dfm function that does this already, or a simpler way with code less clumsy than I envision doing it in my logic described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem: you want to keep the features with the highest document frequencies within group.  I'd do this by splitting the dfm by group, and then using the very versatile `dfm_trim()` function with ranked document frequency filtering.

To set up your dfm as a dfm, and add a document variable:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

# set up dfm
dfmat <- as.dfm(data.frame(
  t1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  t2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  t4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  t5 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
))
dfmat$labels <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
```

Now split the dfm across the groups, and choose those ranked highest.  (To change this, change the `min_docfreq` value.)

```r
# chooses the top document frequency by group
tokeep <- lapply(unique(dfmat$labels), function(x) {
  dfm_subset(dfmat, labels == x) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_docfreq = 1, docfreq_type = "rank")
})
```

The results look this by group, and are easily recombined using `rbind()`.

```r
tokeep
## [[1]]
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (0.0% sparse) and 1 docvar.
##     features
## docs t3
##    1  1
##    2  1
##    3  1
## 
## [[2]]
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 2 features (33.3% sparse) and 1 docvar.
##     features
## docs t4 t5
##    4  1  0
##    5  1  1
##    6  0  1

# make back into a single dfm
do.call(rbind, tokeep)
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 3 features (61.1% sparse).
##     features
## docs t3 t4 t5
##    1  1  0  0
##    2  1  0  0
##    3  1  0  0
##    4  0  1  0
##    5  0  1  1
##    6  0  0  1
```